# How do interpret ZRSSI signal strength from cellular modem?

Tags: signals, modem

I have a ZTE modem on a Raspberry Pi. When I issue AT +ZTRSSI I get back three numbers - an example is 69,12,150. Can someone tell me how I turn that into dBM signal strength?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance its commands set is any similar to this? https://www.kogitae.fr/zte-at-commands-3g-modem-wiki.htm

If that's the case, the first number is an actual RSSI (in negative dBm).